# Execute Unit tests in windows app container

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, desktop-bridge

I have a .net core 3.1 app which is packaged using a `Windows Application Packaging Project`.

<strike>I want to write unit tests for this, but some code will only work executed in an app container. How can I test such an app.</strike>

**EDIT**
My unit tests need to execute the test like running with Desktop Bridge.

Comment: WAPProj does not result in an AppContainer unless you specify "partial trust" - did you do that? And what specifically isn't working?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT The [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cfapi/build-a-cloud-file-sync-engine#desktop-bridge) says `Sync engines using the cloud files APIs are designed to use the Desktop Bridge as an implementation requirement.`. In the beginning I tried to use it directly without App package. It was not completely failing, but icons were not correct sometimes callbacks were not called. It behaved very strangely sometimes. But after using App Package Project it just started working. I was under the impression that it has to do with app container, I'll change it.